# Is adding 2FA support through Google Authenticator or similar services available for developers as a free service?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor-authentication

A discussion on Twitter about 2FA made me consider something: I don't actually know the costs related to adding 2FA to an existing project, whether that be through Google Authenticator, Authy, a different Authenticator service or your own app. Let's exclude a homebrew app and assume we want to add 2FA support to our service through a third party app. Is it possible to do this without any upfront or recurring service related costs, both for us as the company and for the user as the customer who needs to install the app? I did some Googling and read something about Okta, but it was not entirely clear how this service factors in.

Comment: There are no costs associated with using the Authenticator App and there are also other free alternatives which also implement the same [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_one-time_password). But of course your application must be able to handle this second factor - which means costs of implementation and management for you. Okta and others help you with the latter one (and way more) - and expect you to pay for this service.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm that is used by Google Authenticator and similar tools, such as Authy, is called TOTP and is defined in [RFC 6238](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) as an open standard.

It's possible to implement this for a typical web service using a standard library implementing TORP for your language, or manually using HMAC with a suittable hash function, a CSPRNG, and a QR code generator.  Unless you are well acquainted with cryptography, I'd recommend using an appropriate library for your environment.

There are some companies who will try to sell you on a proprietary solution which uses their custom app and special software, but it's not necessary and using the standard TOTP approach allows the user to store all of their credentials in one app and easily transfer it to a new device, which is a substantial benefit.  In addition, using standard TOTP is free.

Similarly, there is also 2FA support using security keys (or the user's device code on Android) called WebAuthn, which is also an open specification and can be implemented without charge.  WebAuthn, unlike TOTP, is typically resistant to phishing, and may be an interesting option to allow in addition to TOTP.

Answer (score 0):

There is something in between - freemium. In other words, it's free until a certain threshold is reached.

Example: https://rapidapi.com/chdan/api/otp-authenticator/ (here the cap is of 1000 requests per day)

1. Generate a "secret" code:

```py
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com")

headers = {
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': "SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY",
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': "otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com"
}

conn.request("POST", "/new_v2/", headers=headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Server will return you a secret code (e.g. IH225HMVWDS3XJVY).

2. Generate QR codes:

```
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com")

payload = "secret=IH225HMVWDS3XJVY&account=User1&issuer=HomeCorp"

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': "SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY",
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': "otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com"
}

conn.request("POST", "/enroll/", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

Server returns an url. Pull its PNG data and you get a QR code. Scan it with Google Authenticator app and you'll see TOTPs being generated every 30 seconds.

3. Now validate TOTPs:

```py
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com")

payload = "secret=IH225HMVWDS3XJVY&code=425079"

headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'X-RapidAPI-Key': "SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY",
    'X-RapidAPI-Host': "otp-authenticator.p.rapidapi.com"
}

conn.request("POST", "/validate/", payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

That's a C# realization using HttpClient lib, but RapidAPI generates code snippets in most popular programming languages/libs - quite handy